# Order a column name with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am just now getting into this website called CodeFights that gives developers a challenge. I wanted to ask you lovely people at stack overflow to maybe steer me in the right direction with a MySql challenge.. 
First it gives, a description and if this [link](https://codefights.com/challenge/gGtnm9PeWhBYH8fid?utm_source=COW&utm_medium=email&utm_term=challenge_of_the_week&utm_campaign=4.5.17) works for you, maybe you can help me solve the question because it will take too long to type.

If not my answer to 50% of the question is simply:
SELECT chapter_name from book_chapters;

It also requires that you order the chapter name in ASCENDING order and I've tried
select chapter_name from book_chapter order by chapter_number ASC;
but no luck,
They only want one column from book_chapters and its, chapter_name.

A little stumped.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to convert the roman numerals to the arabic (base 10) representation.

But that isn't really necessary.

A series of simple string replacements will do the trick.

In terms of ranking roman numeral "digits" ...

```
    I < V < X < L < C < D < M
```

If we replace 'L' with 'Y' and 'C' with 'Z', and (for now) we ignore 'D' and 'M', then this string comparison will hold true:

```
    'I' < 'V' < 'X' < 'Y' < 'Z'
```

The trick here is that we're selecting replacement characters that are in a specific collating sequence, so that we can do a sort.

The other issue we have to deal is the special cases of the "subtraction" (backwards) replacements

```
    IV
    IX
    XL
    XC
```

If we replace those cases with representations with four repeated characters... i.e. `IV` -> `IIII`,  `IX` -> `VIIII`, etc. then that gets us string values that can be sorted.

So, we could use an ORDER BY clause something like this:

```
  ORDER BY REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                       UPPER( chapter_num ) 
                     ,'C','Z')
                   ,'L','Y')
                 ,'IV','IIII')
               ,'IX','VIIII')
             ,'XY','XXXX')
           ,'XZ','YXXXX')
```

This works for roman numeral values up to 399. That's when we run into the 'D'.

To handle numbers 400 or greater, we could replace the `'D'` with a character "greater than" `'Z'` in the collating sequence, such as the left square bracket `'['`. And we can replace `'M'` with a right square bracket `']'`. And make the appropriate replacements for special cases `'CD'` and `'CM'`.

We need to verify that the collating sequence for character strings, that this holds true:

```
    'I' < 'V' < 'X' < 'Y' < 'Z' < '[' < ']'
```

Then we can extend support for roman numerals beyond 399 ...

```
  ORDER BY REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                         REPLACE(
                           REPLACE(
                             REPLACE(
                               UPPER( chapter_num )
                             ,'M',']')
                           ,'D','[')
                         ,'C','Z')
                       ,'L','Y')
                     ,'IV','IIII')
                   ,'IX','VIIII')
                 ,'XY','XXXX')
               ,'XZ','YXXXX')
             ,'Z[','ZZZZ')
           ,'Z]','[ZZZZ')
```